# Spring-boot 2.x version infinispanCacheManager is not working

Tags: spring-boot, caching, spring-boot-actuator

With Spring boot 2.x 
1) infinispanCacheManager is not working 
2) Metrix Information /metrics Endpoint is not working, and
3) default bootstrap for infnispan ?﻿